# Pandas Pivot Table on single column and return multiples of the same columns with values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have the following sample data set.

```
dict = {'Animal':["Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog"],
        'Date': ["3/1/22", "2/28/22", "2/1/22", "2/4/22","2/3/22"],
        'score':['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass','Fail', 'Pass']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)


Animal  Date        Note
Cat     3/1/2022    Pass
Cat     2/28/2022   Fail
Cat     2/1/2022    Pass
Dog     2/4/2022    Fail
Dog     2/3/2022    Pass
```

And I am trying to get the following pivot table:

```
Animal  Date_1     Note_1   Date_2      Note_2  Date_3      Note_3
Cat     3/1/2022    Pass    2/28/2022   Fail    2/1/2022    Pass
Dog     2/4/2022    Fail    2/3/2022    Pass    nan         nan
```

I tried using pandas `pivot` function but I get the wrong results

```
pd.pivot(df
          , index=['Animal']
          , values = ['Date','score']
          , columns = ['Date','score']
         ).reset_index()
```

This outputs:

```
      Animal    Date    score
Date        3/1/22  2/28/22 2/1/22  2/4/22  2/3/22  3/1/22  2/28/22 2/1/22  2/4/22  2/3/22
score       Pass    Fail    Pass    Fail    Pass    Pass    Fail    Pass    Fail    Pass
0     Cat   3/1/22  2/28/22 2/1/22  NaN     NaN     Pass    Fail    Pass    NaN     NaN
1     Dog   NaN     NaN     NaN     2/4/22  2/3/22  NaN     NaN     NaN     Fail    Pass
```

Comment: shouldn't be the value of Note_3 in row cats `Pass` ?

Comment: It could be done with the following but I was hoping for to utilize the pivot function. `df_1 = df.groupby('Animal').nth(0).reset_index()
df_2 = df.groupby('Animal').nth(1).reset_index()
df_3 = df.groupby('Animal').nth(2).reset_index()

df_combined = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='left', on=['Animal'])
df_combined = pd.merge(df_combined, df_3, how='left', on=['Animal'])`

Comment: There are lots of approaches in the linked Q&A. But `dfp = df.pivot_table(index='Animal', columns=df.groupby('Animal').cumcount() + 1, aggfunc='first').sort_index(axis=1, level=1)` works. Follow up with collapsing of multiindex like `dfp.columns = dfp.columns.map(lambda t: '_'.join(map(str, t)))` and you're set (from [my answer](/a/69089594/15497888)). Another similar option [here](/a/57670971/15497888).